# What's wrong with my solution of SearchInsert?

Tags: java, algorithm, search

puzzle:

> Given a sorted array and a target value, return the index if the target is found. If not, return the index where it would be if it were inserted in order.
>
> You may assume no duplicates in the array.

And my code here:

```
public class Solution {
    public static int searchInsert(int[] nums, int target) {
        return searchInsert(nums, target, 0, nums.length-1);
    }
    
    private static int searchInsert(int[] nums, int target, int start, int end) {
        if(start <= end) {
            return target <= nums[start] ? start : (start+1);
        }
        int m = (start + end) / 2;
        if(nums[m] == target) {
            return m;
        } else if(nums[m] < target) {
            return searchInsert(nums, target, m+1, end);
        } else {
            return searchInsert(nums, target, start, m-1);
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] nums = {1, 3};
        System.out.print(searchInsert(nums, 4);
    }
}
```

The result turns out like this:

> Input:
>
> [1,3]
>
> 4
>
> Output:
>
> 1
>
> Expected:
>
> 2

I've simulate the process of this input over and over again on paper, but just cannot figure out how my code could output `2`.

Please help me with this, thx in advance.

Comment: Issue is over here.. `if(start <= end) {
            return target <= nums[start] ? start : (start+1);
        }` You could debug further.

Comment: It would help if you provided all of the code

Comment: Please read [mcve] and take care to read the article about debugging linked at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Have a main method to make it an MCVE. Ho ho ho.

Answer (score 1):

The condition:

```
start <= end
```

is incorrect. The condition is true immediately for a non-zero length array, because `start == 0` and `end == <something which is at least 0>`, so it will return either `start` or `start+1` straight away - in your case, `start+1`.

Comment: Well, I made a stupid mistake here and wasted so much time to find out why this code didn't work. It should be `start >= end`:(